# Topology Manager for CM and/or CD?

Tags: topology-manager

I'm looking at [Nuno's Topology Manager example code](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/Exploring-Topology-Manager/blob/master/ExploreTopMan/ExploreTopMan/Program.cs). His examples include getting:

- Environment IDs and statuses (offline)
- Purposes
- Base and Context URLs

Is `Tridion.TopologyManager.Client` something you would use for CM only?

Would it be a good fit to discover or get information in delivery or the presentation server (e.g. to retrieve and display a URL)?

Comment: Tridion.Clients.ContentDelivery.dll (it is avalable in a GAC) is used to communicate between CM and CD. Using methods from this dll you can instantiate Discovery Service with DeployerCapability, PreviewWebServiceCapability, WebCapability or get information about these capabilities from your Discovery service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I would say the Topology Manager client is meant for CM only. Especially since it likely won't work on Unix-based operating systems :)

Generally, the approach on the CD side is to configure the URL to the Discovery Service -- which then allows you to authenticate, find all of the capabilities and URLs to other services, etc. That information would be restricted to the current Environment, though.